# Sending commands with parameter ESC/POS thermal printer

Tags: java, printing, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm having a problem with my Java ESC/POS thermal printer print command.
I'm able to print texts, but when I try to do the POS commands, they won't run.

Currently, the command I'm trying to execute is 'ESC 3 n', in which I define n to be the line spacing.

Current code:

```
    printHorizontalLine();

    byte[] line = {ESC, (byte)'3', 5};
    printBytes(line);

    printHorizontalLine();
```

---

```
    public void printBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    String printer = printerName;

    /* Finding the printer of name printer */
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
    PrintService service = findPrintService(printer, services);

    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    // Possible umlaut characters:
    try {
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
        job.print(doc, null);

    } catch (PrintException e) {
        // Print had a problem
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to reduce the distance of both horizontal lines (two texts that I'm able to print) to 5 instead of the default 31. The problem is: **there is no difference**.

I want the lines to be closer to each other

Comment: Can you show the code of printHorizontalLine() as well?